# How can I use the same form in multiple views

Tags: cakephp, dry

I am using CakePHP 2.4. I have a blog where I can add and edit posts. When I implemented my `edit.ctp`, I recognized, that I have the same code in the view `add.ctp`:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create();
    echo $this->Form->input('headline');
    echo $this->Form->input('text', array('type' => 'textarea');
    echo $this->Form->end('Save');
?>
```

(simplified code)

Regarding CakePHP´s recommendation, I want to keep my code DRY. What is the best way to define the form only one time and use it in both views?

Comment: [Elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements)?

Comment: you can also render a view using $this->render('edit'); in add if you have edit.ctp which has same code you want in add.ctp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a view in the folder Element with the form code

```
// app/View/Elements/postForm.ctp

<?php
    echo $this->Form->create();
    echo $this->Form->input('headline');
    echo $this->Form->input('text', array('type' => 'textarea');
    echo $this->Form->end('Save'); 
?>
```

Then include it in your desired views

```
echo $this->element('postForm');
```

Comment: Works fine in CakePHP. Thanks.

Comment: If add and edit are 100% identical, just override which view is being rendered in the add/edit action in the controller: `$this->render('postForm');`  If you create 100% identical forms as elements, you'll end up with add and edit views that only have the line `echo $this->element('postForm');`, which is sort of wasteful.

Comment: @Kai: Thank you for your comment. I am using 100% identical forms in the views edit and add. But the both views are not 100% identical. Except the form they differ in some html-elements.